# Android client doesn't get server reply

Tags: android, client-server

I have an Android client which sends data to Java server. After some server process I want the server to reply back to the client, but I can't get to work.

At first, both client and server got stuck on `readLine()`, so I added `\n` to both but still no change. After a long search here I've tried to close client connection and then the server runs but the client gives an error because the socket is closed. What is the correct way to do it and why?

Client code:

```
private class sendToServer extends AsyncTask<JSONObject, Void, String> {
    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(JSONObject... userData) {
        Socket clientSocket;
        try {
            clientSocket = new Socket("10.0.2.2", 7878);
            BufferedOutputStream  outToServer = new BufferedOutputStream(clientSocket.getOutputStream());
            outToServer.write( (userData[0].toString() + '\n').getBytes() );
            outToServer.flush();

            BufferedReader inFromServer = new BufferedReader(new Inpu    tStreamReader(clientSocket.getInputStream()));
            String reply = inFromServer.readLine();

            outToServer.close();
                Log.d("",reply);

            inFromServer.close();
            clientSocket.close();

        } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

Server Code:

```
@Override
public void run() {
    try {
        BufferedReader inFromClient = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(connection.getInputStream()));
        StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
        String line;
        while ((line = inFromClient.readLine()) != null)
                builder.append(line);

        BufferedOutputStream outToClient = new BufferedOutputStream(connection.getOutputStream());
        outToClient.write( ("ACK" + '\n').getBytes() );
        outToClient.flush();

            inFromClient.close();           
            putToClient.close();

        parseIncomingData(builder.toString());

    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println(e);
    } finally {
        try {
            connection.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.out.println(e);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like your server is going to keep reading lines until null is returned.  This won't happen until the stream gets closed by the other end.  As a test, simply do a single readLine (get rid of the while loop) and see if everything works for a single message.

Alternatively you could send an empty string (or some "special" terminator string) from the client as the last string - then you could check for this "special" string or empty string on the server to break out of the while readline loop.